# Metabolic impact of ambient temperatures/weather on diabetes 2

Tags: reference-request, type-2-diabetes

Studies seem to find that hot weather (possibly in combination with humidity) increases mortality risk in type 2 diabetics (see, for example, [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0013935121000566) or [here](https://journals.plos.org/plosmedicine/article?id=10.1371/journal.pmed.1002612)) as well as the risk of other complications ([here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28701216/)). However, this increased risk often seems to be related to things like a higher likelihood of dehyration or changes in the effectiveness of medication.

At the same time, I have heard anecdotal evidence that blood glucose levels can temporarily improve, for example when travelling to countries with significantly hotter climate than the home country. I appreciate that there may be many confounding factors, such as levels of activity, and differences in diet.

Still, I was wondering whether there are any studies that focus on how high (or low) ambient temperatures affect the metabolism of type 2 diabetics.